# Android studio open external file from app

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get my app to download and open a word document in whatever word processing app the device has using the below code. However, I keep getting *"there was a problem passing the package"* when I try and open it. 
The word document downloads fine, because I can go to files and open it from there. However, when I try and open it from my app it causes the error.

Here is my code for opening the file. I already use it elsewhere in my app to open an APK file and that works fine.

```
public static void OpenFile(Activity activity, String name){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Command Tasks.docx")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DOCX files do not have a MIME type of `application/vnd.android.package-archive`. That MIME type is for APK files.

Either replace `application/vnd.android.package-archive` with the proper MIME type for DOCX files, or do not supply a MIME type and hope that the system figures out the correct MIME type.